# Is is possible to pass parameter to a chained anonymous function callback?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, javascript-objects

I'd like to be able to pass parameters to an anonymous callback, is this possible? See below, thus far its not looking so.

```
var chain = {
    do: function(){
        console.log('blah');
        return this;
    },

    then: function(cb, param){
        cb.apply(param);
    }
}

chain.do().then(function(params){
    console.log(params); // undefined, expecting [1,2]
    console.log(arguments); // [], expecting [1,2]
}, [1,2]);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `apply()` is the context, not the arguments.

Try...

```
cb.apply(this, param);
```

(or whatever you want `this` to be).

Comment: knew I was missing something simple! Thanks